# Present a bilinear form as a sum of symmetric and skew symmetric parts.

Tags: linear-algebra

Present a bilinear form $F(x,y) = x_1y_1+2x_1y_2+2x_2y_2$ as a sum of symmetric and skew symmetric parts.

I tried to do next steps:
$f(x,y)=\frac{f(x,y)+f(y,x)}{2} + \frac{f(x,y)-f(y,x)}{2}$ , where the first number is symmetric and second is skew symmetric.

But I stuck how to continue.

Comment: Those look neither symmetric nor skew-symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have everything in place. Note that $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,y_2)$, then
\begin{align*}
F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})&=x_1y_1+2x_1y_2+2x_2y_2\\
F(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x})&=y_1x_1+2y_1x_2+2y_2x_2\\
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})+F(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x})}{2} & =\frac{1}{2}\left(2x_1y_1+4x_2y_2+2(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)\right)\\
&=\color{red}{x_1y_1+2x_2y_2+(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)}.
\end{align*}
You can check that the expression obtained is symmetric (swapping $x_i$ with $y_i$ will not change the expression).

Similarly you can get $\frac{F(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})-F(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x})}{2}$

Comment: @Metso I don't get that.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown: what is wrong? this is standard exercise as I see. What is your opinion?

Comment: @Anurag A : thank you very much